# Iota wallet balance is 0 and tangle explorer only shows received and 0 sent

Tags: wallet

I can't find my funds and have tried everything from every forum, and what I find very odd is that the below is the 1st wallet I send my funds from bitfinex to

https://iotasear.ch/address/CZATYVVNR9C9VKXFJTPFCALZTDOUGSRNJLEGVVOFLQSLJKXIXQEIAIBDNMXKYVHOUZHYUWVXXWSKE9JKL

I then created a new seed in August and transfered all the funds to the new wallet and saw the funds appear in the new seed.

My question is this,  based on the above wallet which is from my first seed, no funds were transferred out so why is the balance 0??

Is there a way to trace the wallet where my funds should be as I don't know which seed my funds should be in.

Comment: When you said you have tried everything, you surely have tried to attach addresses in your new seed with the wallet, haven't you?

Answer (score 3):

When you check the [snapshot after the transition period](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmeb4B5AEi5MWTreKPRtufBFRFWRVTpZkBpX6FeaXCAe3B) you will see that your address is listed as CURL_UNUSED there.

That means, that the funds on this address have never been transitioned to the new Kerl address scheme (in August or September), and were now [taken in custody by the IOTA foundation (see #1.1)](https://forum.iota.org/t/snapshot-public-validation-22-09-2017/4256).

If you already did a reclaim for your old seed, this is all you can do, as the IOTA foundation [has not processed the reclaim queue yet](https://forum.helloiota.com/1242/Reclaim-Status). If you did not, get the latest wallet and go through the reclaim process, entering your old seed and a new unused seed.